# How to pass value of a radiobuttonfor to onclick method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of radiobuttonfor and if the answer id is 4 (Like "Other" option where we can enter details) there is a textbox to be displayed to enter the "Other" details.
So I want to disable that textbox first and enable only if user press answerID 4 ie "Other" option. How to do this?

What I did is :

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DemoQ1Answers.Count(); i++)
                {

                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.selectedAnswerIDforQ1, Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID, new { @onclick = "onQ1RadioChanged()" })
                            @Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerDescription
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerDescription)
                            @if (Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID == 4)
                            {

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].DemoQ1Other, new { disabled = "disabled" })
                            }

                        </div>

                }
```

How can I know the value of the radiobuttonfor to that onclick function so that I can check the value inside function call to enable the textbox.

Below is my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    //alert("inside javascript ");
});

  function onQ1RadioChanged() {
       alert ('(@(Model.selectedAnswerIDforQ1))')
        alert("onQ1RadioChanged called");

        if (@(Model.selectedAnswerIDforQ1)== 4) {
            //enable textbox ??
        }
    }
```

This code is not even calling the onQ1RadioChanged method and no alert is even displayed.

Code from developer tools :

```
<p>What is your highest level of education?</p>
            <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input id="selectedAnswerIDforQ1" name="selectedAnswerIDforQ1" onclick="onQ1RadioChanged()" type="radio" value="1" />
                            Undergraduate Degree (Baccalaureate)
                            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AnswerID must be a number." data-val-required="The AnswerID field is required." id="DemoQ1Answers_0__AnswerID" name="DemoQ1Answers[0].AnswerID" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            <input id="DemoQ1Answers_0__AnswerDescription" name="DemoQ1Answers[0].AnswerDescription" type="hidden" value="Undergraduate Degree (Baccalaureate)" />


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">


                            <input id="selectedAnswerIDforQ1" name="selectedAnswerIDforQ1" onclick="onQ1RadioChanged()" type="radio" value="2" />
                            Master’s Degree
                            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AnswerID must be a number." data-val-required="The AnswerID field is required." id="DemoQ1Answers_1__AnswerID" name="DemoQ1Answers[1].AnswerID" type="hidden" value="2" />
                            <input id="DemoQ1Answers_1__AnswerDescription" name="DemoQ1Answers[1].AnswerDescription" type="hidden" value="Master’s Degree" />


                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input id="selectedAnswerIDforQ1" name="selectedAnswerIDforQ1" onclick="onQ1RadioChanged()" type="radio" value="4" />
                            Other:
                            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AnswerID must be a number." data-val-required="The AnswerID field is required." id="DemoQ1Answers_3__AnswerID" name="DemoQ1Answers[3].AnswerID" type="hidden" value="4" />
                            <input id="DemoQ1Answers_3__AnswerDescription" name="DemoQ1Answers[3].AnswerDescription" type="hidden" value="Other:" />

                        <input disabled="disabled" id="DemoQ1Answers_3__DemoQ1Other" name="DemoQ1Answers[3].DemoQ1Other" type="text" value="" />

                        </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: When your ASP renders, what does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: @Doug : A question with 4 options like 1. Degree 2. Masters  3.PHD 4.Other (with a textbox to write the education)

Comment: lol -- i appreciate the candor, but I mean can you paste the code for the radio buttons, as how the browser sees it?

Comment: @Doug : I will copy the code from Developer tools:  But my view code is written above. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Doug : I have copied it in the original post

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript you can bind HTML elements' triggered events to call functions. So a quick step-by-step:

1. Capture all of the radio buttons you want to listen to for a change
2. Loop through the NodeList collection to individually bind the element's eventListener for 'change'
3. When a change occurs, ask the JavaScript to trigger a function (to send parameters back to the function, its easier to nest the call inside an anonymous function)
4. And from there, you have your function with the value from the radio button -- apply the logic of your choice.

```js
// Use JS to capture all of your Radio Buttons
const radioButtons = document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="radioTest"]');
// Get the textbox
const txtBox = document.getElementById('txtBox');

for( let radioBtn of radioButtons ){
  // Loop through and bind each radio button to trigger
  // the function on the change event
  radioBtn.addEventListener('change', function(){
    onQ1RadioChanged( this.value, this.checked ) 
  });
}

function onQ1RadioChanged( val, check ){
  // Do something with the val(ue)
  // Input comes back as a string
  if( val === '4' ){
    txtBox.disabled = false;
  }else{
    txtBox.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
input[disabled]{ background-color: #F7F7F7; }
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <label>Radio 1<input type="radio" name="radioTest" id="radio1" value="1" /></label> <br />
  <label>Radio 2<input type="radio" name="radioTest" id="radio2" value="2" /></label> <br />
  <label>Radio 3<input type="radio" name="radioTest" id="radio3" value="3" /></label> <br />
  <label>Radio 4<input type="radio" name="radioTest" id="radio4" value="4" /></label> <br />
  <input type="text" id="txtBox" disabled/> <br />
</div>
```

Just now looking back at the provided code from the ASP -> HTML output...

If this is your desired output, then you need to update your onclick to pass the `this` keyword (which will pass back a reference to the HTML element in the JavaScript)

```
<input type="radio" onclick="onQ1RadioChanged( this );" ... />
```

And then in the JavaScript, set up the function to receive a parameter to represent the element...

```
function onQ1RadioChanged( element ){ ... }
```

And then inside the function you can reference the radio button's value...

```
function onQ1RadioChanged( element ){
    if( element.value === '4' ){ ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I was wondering if I pass "this" as a parameter, how can it be its value? It is just an element, right? So how can I check its value is 4?Should it be this.value ? But even that doesn't work, it is not going to my function and none of the alerts are even popping up.

Comment: so when passing the keyword `this` it just references the DOM element -- when you get it to the function whatever the parameter name is then represents `this` (the radio button) -- in my example this is passed to the function which then captures/assigns it to a parameter variable 'element'. From there you should be able to query attributes of the element

Comment: Good thing to keep in mind is that input from HTML returns to JavaScript as text (a string).  So once you have the element in your function you should be able to check the value as `element.value`

Comment: Oh, but don't pass `this` as a string itself -- then it's just sending a word to the function.  `onclick="onQ1RadioChanged( this )` vs. `onclick="onQ1RadioChanged( 'this' )`

Comment: A good double check would be to `console.log( element )` to make sure what the function is receiving is in fact the HTML element you're expecting

Comment: I tried both, none of the alerts are even popping up.

Comment: Here,  `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.selectedAnswerIDforQ1, Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID, new { @onclick = "onQ1RadioChanged('this')" }) `
In this @onlick =" " entire thing inside is considered as a string, Is it the right way?

Comment: almost there :) just remove the single quotes around `this` and that should be accurate -- the function not being called is a different pickle ...

Comment: `console.log( element )` is also not working, It is not going inside the function, I think

Comment: not being able to hit the function with onclick="..." is a pain.  A lot of the time this can be resolved with how you position JavaScript in your HTML.  Try moving the JavaScript to the beginning or the end of the document (convention says it should be at the bottom, but if it doesn't work there, then what's the point?)

Comment: Removed single quotes around this and still doesn't go to function. Or log the element.Mine is at the very bottom, let me try to put it at top

Comment: If moving the JavaScript does not fix the function call, then the next idea would be to link the function to the browser's window element `window.onQ1RadioChanged = function( element ){ ... }` You can somewhat see this in action via this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLLow0bw/42/

Comment: One more question, should the function call be inside document.ready or outside of it? Mine is outside.

Comment: Outside ... if it's inside, it won't be accessible to the call (it's scope would be limited to the function used with document.ready)

Comment: I tried moving it to top in the head section and still no luck

Comment: Got It Doug :) Thanks a lot, I was spending the whole day for this.
I had a check like this `if (@(Model.selectedAnswerIDforQ1)== 4) {
                //enable textbox ??
            }` which has a error called invalid statement ==, so i commented that check and it went tinside the function